# Photoshop CC: Make selection inside grid cell

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I'm using Photoshop's built in grid feature and I'd like to know if there's a quick way to create a selection that will expand to be the dimensions of any given grid cell.

In Aseprite there's a feature where while you have the Marquee tool selected you can double click inside a grid cell to create a selection inside of it.

Is there a similar feature like this in Photoshop?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is for making tile based art for game dev purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Rectangular Marquee tool to  "fixed size" in the tool options along the top, set the width and height to the grid size, and enable Snap to grid in Photoshop.  Then a single click near the top left corner of the cell will select the cell.  Since I'm not familiar with the software you mentioned, and don't know why you want to do that, then I can't be sure how useful this will be for you.

Here's a 10px grid. Marquee set to "fixed size". Height and width set to 10px. I'm adding to the selection by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as I click.

[image]

Comment: Ah great this is super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

*I've accepted Billy Kerr's answer, but I came up with something else while waiting. I'll include this in case someone else happens upon this and is seeking an alternate solution.*

I made a grid of alternating squares that match my grid in a separate layer. Using the magic wand tool you can make a selection in one of the grids while the layer is selected. This even works if the layer is invisible.

It's a bit hacky, but I thought it was a cute solution.

[image: Grid Selection]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with hacky solutions . . . If they work for you, that's all that matters!

Answer (score -4):

1. Select photoshop → preferences → reviews, grids & slices.
2. Specify grid as needed.
3. Select view → discloses → grid; then take a look at bonus offers.
4. Inspect sight → break to the grid; after that check breeze.
5. Activate the Paths home window if it isn't currently noticeable. ...
6. Utilize the pen tool (P ). ...
7. Make use of the program selection device (A, black arrowhead).

Comment: There may be some translation problems with you answer. Unfortunately, it's almost incomprehensible.  Also please don't bold everything.  Use bullet points or a numbered list to show steps.